# Android Studio Deep Link using URI

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking

Like the dozen other threads out there, I am trying to debug directly on a device using Android Studio via a uri. But I can't seem to find an exact example of someone doing so from Android Studio using the Edit Configuration. Sure something simple I am missing...

Here is what I am doing:

1. Add the uri to the Edit Configuration:

[image]

2. Here is the intent in the AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
       <activity
       android:name="com.mayapp.StartActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard|navigation"
       android:label="StartActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme=myapp" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
3. The following error shows up when I try to debug:

[image]

As Text:

```
     11/21 13:15:05: Launching MyApp
    Launching deeplink: myapp%3A%2F%2Fdispatch.

    $ adb shell setprop log.tag.AppIndexApi VERBOSE
    $ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d myapp%3A%2F%2Fdispatch -D
    Error while executing: am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d myapp%3A%2F%2Fdispatch -D
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=myapp://dispatch }
    Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent  act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=myapp://dispatch flg=0x10000000 

Error while Launching URL
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it would seem that there are several problems to what I was doing. What is interesting is that the way the AndroidManifest.xml was configured some 4 years ago seemed to be working, but to run in Android Studio not only does the `scheme` need to be specified but also the `home` in the Intent. In my case I have several actions associated with the same `scheme`, so the answer was to have multiple data sections within the same `intent`. I could not find any Android documentation on that, but I could have just missed it. So for anyone who might encounter this in the future here is what I did:

1. In the AndroidManifest.XML define the `intent` just like I did, but make sure there is a `home` also. Obviously what you want the app to do when it does open can be different, seems to be a lot of info on that around so I am not including it here. For each action you want to trigger off of, add a new `data` section:

   ```
     <activity
       android:name="com.myapp.StartActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard|navigation"
       android:label="StartActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="anondispatch"/>
           <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="dispatch"/>
           <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="openform"/>
           <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="opendispatch"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. In the code you can catch the opening in the `onIntent()` method in the specified `activity` (in my example it is `StartActivity`). Here is a sample of the code parsing out the elements you are looking for:

   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)  {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       setIntent(intent);
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       if (intent.getAction() != null) {
           if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                   Uri uri = intent.getData();
                   String host = uri.getHost(); `
                   String uriStr = uri.toString();
                   if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("anondispatch")) {
                       // parse out that you want
                   }
          else if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("opendispatch")) {
                       // parse out that you want
                   }
                   else if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("openform")) {
                       // parse out that you want
                   } 
                   else if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("dispatch)) {
                       // parse out that you want
                   }
               }
           }
       } 
   }
3. Update the configuration, from the Edit Configuration so the debugger can run on a remote device via USB by using the following:

[image]